# Applying a Single to an ObservableSource and not over-reading

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm pretty new to RX in general, and rxjava in particular, pardon mistakes.

This operation depends on a two async operations.

The first uses a filter function to attempt to get a single entity from a list returned by an async Observable.

The second is an async operation that communicates with a device and produces an Observable of status updates.

I want to take the Single that is created from the filter function, apply that to `pairReader(...)`, and subscribe to its Observable for updates. I can get this to work as shown, but only if I include the `take(1)` commented, otherwise I get an exception because the chain tries to pull another value from the Single.

```
  Observable<DeviceCredential> getCredentials() {
    return deviceCredentialService()
            .getCredentials()
            .flatMapIterable(event -> event.getData());
  }

  Single<Organization> getOrgFromCreds(String orgid) {
    return getCredentials()
      // A device is logically constrained to only have a single cred per org
      .map(DeviceCredential::getOrganization)
      .filter(org -> org.getId().equals(orgid))
      .take(1)  // Without this I get an exception
      .singleOrError();
  }

  Function<Organization, Observable<Reader.EnrollmentState>> pairReader(String name) {
    return org -> readerService().pair(name, org);
  }

getOrgFromCreds(orgid)
  .flatMapObservable(pairReader(readerid))
  .subscribe(state -> {
     switch(state) {
       case BEGUN:
         LOG.d(TAG, "Pairing begun");
         break;
       case PAIRED:
         LOG.d(TAG, "Pairing success");
         callback.success();
         break;
       case NOTIFIED_SERVER:
         LOG.d(TAG, "Pairing server notified");
         break;
     }},
     error -> {
       Crashlytics.logException(error);
       callback.error(error.getLocalizedMessage());
     });
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses everyone! It looks like my problem was because the service (part of a closed-source SDK) was returning multiple sets, one for data stored in the local cache, and one for data stored in the cloud. Luckily they have a flag for the different sources (in the `event`) and I was able to filter the duplicate data out.

Comment: You should post this as an answer. I don't see any reason why it should be closed. Others who are new to this framework may have the same problem. If you are still convinced that it's useless, you can ping me back and I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here turned out to be that the API was designed in an odd way (and unfortunately has extremely poor documentation). I couldn't figure out why I was getting duplicates, and thought I was using `flatMapIterable` incorrectly.

What the `deviceCredentialService.getCredentials()` call actually creates is an observable that emits `DataEvent` objects which are simple wrappers over a list of results, and with a flag of where the results came from.

The API designer wanted to allow the user to use locally cached data to fill the UI immediately while a longer request to a REST API executes. The `DataEvent.from` property is an enum that flags the source, either from the local device cache or from the remote API call.

The way I solved this was to simply ignore the results coming from local cache and only emit results from the API:

```
  Observable<DeviceCredential> getCredentials() {
    return deviceCredentialService()
      .getCredentials()
      // Only get creds from network
      .filter(e -> e.getFrom() == SyncedDataSourceObservableFactory.From.SOURCE)
      .flatMapIterable(e -> e.getData());
  }

  Single<Organization> getOrgFromCreds(String orgid) {
    return getCredentials()
      // A device is logically constrained to only have a single cred per org
      .map(DeviceCredential::getOrganization)
      .filter(org -> org.getId().equals(orgid))
      .singleOrError();
  }
```

The plan then is to use memoization to cache entities in a way that gives the implementing app access to cache invalidation. Since the provided interface doesn't allow squelching the API call, there is no way to work only with cache if the app feels its is fresh.

Answer (score 0):

If the source stream emits more than one item, `singleOrError()` is supposed to emit an error. [Doc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#firstOrError--)

For your case, use either `first()` or `firstOrError()` instead.

```
  Single<Organization> getOrgFromCreds(String orgid) {
    return getCredentials()
      .map(DeviceCredential::getOrganization)
      .filter(org -> org.getId().equals(orgid))
      .firstOrError();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you need to make some action using previously retrieved async data. So, you could use [.zip()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator.
Here is an example:

```
Observable.zip(
                getOrgFromCreds().toObservable(),
                getCredentials(),
                (first, second) -> /*create output object here*/
)
                .subscribe(
                        (n) -> /*do onNext*/,
                        (e) -> /*do onError*/
                );
```

Note, that `.zip()` operator will wait for both emission from two streams, and then it will create outer emission using the function you provided in "create output object here".
If you don't want to wait for both items - you can use [.combineLatest()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html).